# Try/catch doesn't catch an exception in Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

as the title says, `try/catch` doesn't catch throwed exception.

Here is my code:

```
public function edit($id)
{
    try {
        $this->permissions($id);   
        return $this->redirect(['edit/list']);

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        Yii::$app->session->setFlash('error', Yii::t('app', 'PERMISSIONS_NOT_FOUND'));
    }   
}
```

I'm trying to catch an exception which is in `permissions()` method. Permissions method is:

```
private function persimssions($id)
{
    $permitted = false;

    if (!$permitted) {
        throw new ForbiddenHttpException(Yii::t('app', 'MODULE_NO_PERMISSIONS'));
    }
}
```

Could someone explain me what is wrong? Thanks for any help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I almost sure that your `Exception` is in fact `yii\db\Exception` - check this in `use` statements. If so it's obvious that it will not catch `ForbiddenHttpException`.

If you want to catch all exceptions write `\Exception` in `catch` or add proper `use` statement.

Comment: In my `uses` I have `use yii\web\ForbiddenHttpException;`, but it still doesn't work

Comment: I told you what to do in my last sentence.